# Does Javascript support the short ternary (rather, variation of) as in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ternary-operator, short-circuiting

I've become fond of PHP's support for the "short ternary", omitting the second expression:

```
// PHP

$foo = 'hello';
$bar = '';

echo $foo ?: 'world'; // hello
echo $bar ?: 'world'; // world
```

Does Javascript support any sort of syntax like this? I've tried `?:` resulting in a syntax error. I'm aware of boolean short circuits, but that's not feasible for what I'm currently doing; that being:

```
// Javascript

var data = {
    key: value ?: 'default'
};
```

Any suggestions? (*I could wrap it in an immediately invoked anonymous function, but that seems silly*)

Comment: @NullUserException - I'm using jQuery, and while I *do* cache my selections, the non-default value is the result of a call to `.data()`, and I was just looking to avoid a second call using the suggested syntax (*and avoid storing the value in a temporary variable*)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var data = {
    key: value || 'default'
};
```

Comment: Nifty! Thanks @SomeGuy - That seems awfully strange though, that Javascript (*read, any language*) would return a non-boolean from such a comparison. I mean, I know it's loosely typed, but sheesh.

Comment: If you are simply trying to allow for default values, [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is a very useful function.

Comment: @Bracketworks: The boolean operators don't return booleans in many (especially functional) languages. They will just return one side of the operator (or `false`).

Comment: @NikiC - Thanks, was not aware of this; any examples besides Javascript that come to mind? I'm simply curious.

Comment: @Bracketworks: Python comes to mind and Lisp. Though probably many more, I just don't know that many languages ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that this may not always work as expected. For example, if `value = 0`, then `data.key` will evaluate to `'default'`. This may not be what you want if `0` is a valid value for `data.key`.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, use `||`.  Unlike PHP, JavaScript's `||` operator will return the first non-falsy value, not a normalized boolean.

```
foo || 'world'
```

Comment: Thanks @jimbojw - SomeGuy beat ya to it though :)

Comment: Yeah, well, that's the price I pay for explaining it rather than just writing the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I already edited that out - agree that it was horrible.

Comment: Better explanation than the accepted answer; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunc = function(foo) {
  foo = foo || 'my default value for foo';
}
```